# Is there a t-test equivalent to Stouffer's z-test?

Tags: t-test, z-test, combining-p-values

I have $k$ pairs of samples from different distributions. For each pair of samples I want to check if the samples are taken from a normal distribution with the same mean and variance. I assume the normal distributions for each pair is different and independent of other pairs. I do not know the mean and variance of any of the distributions.

I am doing a two sample t-test for each of the pairs. I want to combine the $k$ resulting p-values.

I could use Fisher's method but I am wondering about the distribution of the average t-value. If these were z-values rather than t-values I would use Stouffer's z-test. I could also approximate the t-distribution with a z-distribution and than use Stouffer's z-test, but I am not sure if that is a good approximation.

Is there a test like Stouffer's z-test for t-values?

Is there a better way to combine the t-values?

Comment: How about converting t-values into z-values?

Comment: I cannot figure out what this question is asking, because it begins with the objective of checking whether samples have the same *three* properties--normality, means, and variances--but then proceeds to describe a procedure (a t-test) that accomplishes only one of those comparisons. After that it appears to abandon all the preceding context to focus on something else somehow related to "combining t-values." Could you edit it to clear up these uncertainties?

Comment: @whuber The OP is away for over a  year and is therefore unlikely to edit. However, I think I can see what they were asking: they wanted to apply Stouffer's z-score method of combining p-values to the results from a bunch of t-tests; and they were worried that applying $z$-something-something method to $t$-tests is not a good idea because a $t$-test is not a $z$-test. So they asked for a suitable alternative. The answer to this specific confusion is that one can of course proceed with Stouffer's method. (But that other approaches make probably *much* more sense for the overall analysis goal.)

Comment: Hi! Still here :) Thanks for your answers. 
Donda, I tried to avoid using z-values because that could be inaccurate for small sample sizes.
@amoeba, that was exactly my intension. Which other approaches would you suggest?

Answer (score 4):

According to Becker's chapter on combining $p$-values in Cooper and Hedges book you can use

$$
\frac{\sum {t_f}_i (p_i)}{{\sqrt{\sum\frac{f_i}{f_i-2}}}} > z(\alpha)
$$

where ${t_f}_i$ is Student's $t$ with $f_i$ the degrees of freedom $p_i$ the p-value and $\alpha$ is the desired significance value.

She does not give a reference for the method which she attributes to Winer. The resemblance to the formula for Stouffer's method is clear though.

```
Cooper, H and Hedges, L V
A handbook of research synthesis 1994 (Russell Sage, New York)
```

Comment: Could you edit this answer to make it readable?  I am unable to fix up the formula because it is ambiguous and you haven't explained what "$t$" might mean.

Comment: Sorry about that, at the fourth attempt I realised that I cannot use double subscripts for some reason so I have removed them. Now at least it formats OK.

Comment: Double subscripts require braces, as in `$t_{i_j}$` for $t_{i_j}$.

Comment: Now sorted thanks to @whuber. I have added the citation to the book too.

Comment: @mdewey, thanks for your answer! Isn't the suggested method equivalent to Stouffer's z-test?

Comment: As all $f_i$ tend to infinity, yes, it is equivalent to Stouffer's method.