# Can one use Stouffer's method to integrate t-values?

Tags: combining-p-values

I would like to integrate T-statistics values from multiple, independent tests.

How can this be done?

Since my degrees of freedom are many ($n>1000$) I was thinking to use the Stouffer's method, which is really for Z-statistics score. However, with a high $df$ value, the T distribution and the Gaussian distribution should be identical.

Can I use Stouffer's method to integrate T values at $df>1000$?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136415/is-there-a-t-test-equivalent-to-stouffers-z-test?rq=1) for the formula